# Sum interval of multiple NSDate ranges

Tags: ios, nsdate

I can get the time interval between two dates with this method:

```
- (NSString *)calculateTime:(NSDate *)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate *)toDateTime {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:fromDateTime toDate:toDateTime options:0];

    int hours = [conversionInfo hour];
    int minutes = [conversionInfo minute];
    int seconds = [conversionInfo second];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02dh %02dm %02ds", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Assuming I have 3 `NSDate` ranges:

```
2013-02-03 11:20:43  -  2013-02-03 12:42:12 // 01h 21m 29s
2013-02-04 22:11:29  -  2013-02-05 01:56:30 // 03h 45m 01s
2013-02-05 14:02:10  -  2013-02-05 18:32:08 // 04h 29m 58s
```

How can I achieve the same format `%02dh %02dm %02ds` for the interval of all `NSDate` range? In other words, calculating the sum of all intervals.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aim is to calculate durations. A duration is independent from time zones or similar. You can calculate the individual durations and add them.

The easiest way to do this is to calculate the sum of all durations in seconds and only then convert it to a more readable form with hours, minutes and seconds.